# How to draw a stair-step graph using MATLAB for given value?

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, figure

I want to draw a step graph using MATLAB.

In the X-axis, the value starts from `0` and increases like:
`0`, `0+20=20`, `0+20+50=70`, `0+20+50+80=150`, `0+20+50+80+50=200`...
and corresponding Y-axis values are: `Y = [0.76 1.10 1.28 1.35 1.35 1.45 1.50]`

I mean, when:
`X` value is `0-20`, `Y` value is `0.76`
`X` value is `20-70`, `Y` value is `1.10`
`X` value is  `70-150`, `Y` value is `1.28`,
`X` value is `150-200`, `Y` value is `1.35`,...

Please, help me to draw the step graph. My sample code is given below which showed an error due to the different size of `X` and `Y`.

```
X = [0 20 50 80 50 50 50 100];
Y = [0.76 1.10 1.28 1.35 1.35 1.45 1.50];

for i=1:length(X)
    if i==1
       X(i)=0
    else
       X(i) = X(i-1) + X(i)
    end  
end
figure
stairs(X, Y, 'LineWidth',2)
xlim([0 500])
grid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end value of `Y` needs to be repeated.

```
stairs(X, [Y Y(end)], 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Other than that, your loop is replaceable with the built-in function [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

```
X = cumsum(X);
```

[image]